# SQL server Maximum insert statement limit for batch insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

what is maximum statement limit for batch insert like-

```
  Begin
      insert into..... ;
      insert into..... ;
      insert into..... ;
      insert into..... ;
  End
```

Comment: If you find yourself *asking* this sort of question, you ought instead to be looking at alternatives such as `BULK INSERT`, BCP or SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx), the length of the string containing the SQL statement is 65,536 multiplied by the network packet size, with a default packet size of 4k.

(Thanks to @Damien_The_Unbeliever for the clarification)

Comment: Only if you're using network packets containing 1 byte (or you're looking at a different figure than I am) - the limit is `65,536*Network Packet Size` and the default packet size is 4K.